# Implied parameters for super method in python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

In a course about multiple-inheritance I came across this beautiful piece of code.

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(First, self).__init__()
        print("first")

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second, self).__init__()
        print("second")

class Third(Second,First):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Third, self).__init__()
        print("third")

Third();
```

output:

```
first
second
third
```

I was a bit daunted so I started investigating why this stuff even works. I found [a lovely article about this matter](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) that explained some stuff about the mechanics behind `super` pretty well.

Then I started playing with the code and I found out that most of the code is actually redundant. I trimmed stuff step by step until only this poor skeleton remained.

```
class First():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("first")

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("second")

class Third(Second,First):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("third")

Third();
```

This produces the exact same output. Now for `object` I understand that this can be left out, because all classes derive from the base class `object`. No problems there. However I don't quite understand what's behind the arguments that are passed to the `super` method. So I made this final adjustment to check if this would work as well:

```
class First():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("first")

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("second")

class Third(Second,First):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__()
        print("third")

Third();
```

output:

```
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Third
```

I can understand that `self` refers to `Third` in this case. In the case of `super(Third,self)`, `Third` refers to a class which then would suffice as a type I suppose. So is it correct that when calling the `super` method, all of these redundant parts are always implied? Does anyone have some cool documentation about these mechanics other than the link I already found myself? It seems also that the order in which they are called is the reverse order in which the class arguments are listed.
reversing into `class Third(First,Second)` gives output:

```
second
first
third
```

Some additional light on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: `super` with arguments is the original form from python 2, the new argument-free form came with python 3: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Comment: This is special-cased by the *compiler*, actually. It's just syntactic sugar though

Comment: BTW, even the parens are redundant on class definitions: `class First:`. So are semicolons for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `super` was created, in the days of Python 2.x, the arguments to it (the class from which you wanted the "super" to, and the instance where you'd call the method) needed to be explicit.

From the language point of view, `super` was a common call with no special treatment.

On creating Python 3, people agreed that wanting to call the methods in the super-classes is common enough so to deserve special language treatment, and so it is:
In Python 3, the call `super` got special enough that it is handled by the compiler itself (not the language runtime - the compiler, which runs, although in a transparent way, in a complete separated cycle from actually running the program). The compiler arranges for a hidden local variable to be created - it is called `__class__`, and for the parameterless `super()` call to actually be `super(__class__, self)`.  `__class__` points to the class that is defined in the outer `class` statement body. This mechanism is actually one of the more "magic things happening under the hood" that takes place in the otherwise, super-explicit, Python.

The old, explicit, form of `super()`, with the parameters filled in, of course, still works.

One fine way to spot some of these "invisible" mechanisms in action is trying to place a parameterless `super` call inside an ordinary function, not a method: you will see an early-error when trying to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your top example represents the first implementation of `super`.  That implementation was made smarter in a later release, so the second example is the one you should use.  The other is just outdated.  If you are using multiple inheritance, you CAN pass the proper parent class to `super`, but that's a specialized situation.